# Can you compile JavaScript to ARM assembly?

Tags: javascript, assembly, arm, game-boy-advance, nintendo-ds

Can you compile JavaScript to ARM assembly? I'm learning JavaScript right now and I want to know if there is a way to compile it to ARM assembly (to make a GBA/DS game) without writing something in another programming language.

Comment: You can compile Javascript to ARM assembly, that's what JIT compilers like V8 do.  However, the assembly is dynamically generated and cannot be burned onto a game ROM.  Better learn a compiled language.

Comment: The existing toolchains for GBA, at least to my knowledge, are all based on C/C++. If you really want to develop in JS, you could *maybe* find a JS-to-C transpiler (a tool for converting JS source to C source), and have simple little "toy" modules like that (in the sense that transpilers may depend on things that don't exist on something bare-metal like the GBA, so probably only bare things would work), but that would be more pain than it'd be worth, in my opinion, than just doing it in straight C. You'd need to, anyway, for all the hardware stuff that goes on in the GBA.

Comment: it should take you significantly less time to just learn C than to build all the glue to adapt something that does not fit.  If the enjoyment is to make that glue then go for it, sounds like you can.  otherwise if the goal is to create gba programs, choose C or straight asm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahead-of-time compile, not that I know of.  JS is a dynamic language that even supports constructs like `eval()` of a string, so a hypothetical compiler would still have to embed an interpreter or JIT runtime into the executable.  It's also a managed language (sandboxed, and with garbage collection).

`node.js` will JIT to native machine code on the fly, for architectures the V8 engine supports.  But I don't think this will help you make a GBA game, since you'd need to port node.js to the GBA, and have some native libraries to do machine-specific stuff I guess.  A quick search finds some GBA *emulators* written in JS (to run under node.js); I think it's unlikely that you'd find the other thing, a port of node.js to run in a GBA.